# Did X-Men: Magneto Testament ever get a sequel?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

Due to how awesome the five-issue series *X-Men: Magneto Testament* was at fleshing out the character of Magneto, I was just curious, was there ever a sequel made?

One of the main reasons I ask is due to *Origins II*, which continues Wolverine's story from the six-issue series *Origins*. If there is a sequel to *Magneto Testament*, I would love to know. If not, is there a way to follow Magneto's life following *Magneto Testament*?

Comment: There hasn't been a sequel and it looks like there won't be one; http://www.magnetowasright.com/pages/posts/well-nuts.-it-looks-like-we-jumped-the-gun-sequel-to-magneto-testament-only-possible69.php

Comment: Ok, is there any way that you would mind showing the recommended reading order to best read about his life after the book?